# Show that $A$ and $B$ have a common eigenvector

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

Can someone help me solve this problem, i have a deadline.
Let $\operatorname{rank} (AB-BA)$ be less than or equal to $1$. 
If $A$ or $B$ has an eigenspace of dimension greater than or equal to $2$, I need to show that $A$ and $B$ have a common eigenvector.How?

Comment: Good luck with that... Take $A$ to be the identity matrix and $B$ without any eigenvectors as a counter example. Or clarify your question, e.g. do you assume that both $A$ AND $B$ have an eigenspace of the given dimension? Are $A$,$B$ complex matrices, reel,...

Comment: I divided them into two cases. Case one when the rank (AB-BA)=0. This worked using cz we get AB=BA,thus we can transform A and B to a upper triangular matrix by the same unitary matrix, hence, we get a common eigenvector.

Comment: However, the second case where Rank (AB-BA)=1 i can't get anything out of it

Comment: *Both A and B are complex and n×n  matrices.